# Understanding the below behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation

I am getting a seg fault for the below code, is there something wrong?
Here I am trying to shift the bits in `a`.
Also, I know `char *` is a read only memory.

So, we have to copy into `char a[]` and then modify it???

```
    char *str = "abc";

    *str = *str << 1;
```

Comment: You sure do modify string literal .

Comment: You declared a literal string (in read only memory) and tried to modify it. To your update: Yes, `char a[] = "abc";` would allow it to work.

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question.

Comment: You know that is read-only and you still try to modify it, ask your self why. char *str = "abc"; should be **const char *str**

Answer (score 2):

`char*` string literal is pointing to read-only memory. You need to use a char array:

```
char str[] = "Hello";
*str = *str << 1;
```

See: [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly ?

<< is a bitwise operator and *str will not refer to the whole string but only to the first character.

I also recommend you to put parenthesis around your pointer when doing any operations on it to be sure that the bit shift is not done on the address instead of on what is pointed at this address.